# OpenLDAP configuration error ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Tags: configuration, syntax-error, ubuntu-10.04, openldap

I'm using Ubuntu 10.4 server and I'm trying to configure OpenLDAP as a protocol for authentication for SVN and other services. However I quite don't understand how ldap works and after setting a example config I tried to populate it without success. This is the error:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

It seems to be example config problem, more precisely with the admin configuration. However I tried to change it using cryptographic password but got no results. Code config bellow

```
    # Load modules for database type
    dn: cn=module,cn=config
    objectclass: olcModuleList
    cn: module
    olcModuleLoad: back_bdb.la

    # Create directory database
    dn: olcDatabase=bdb,cn=config
    objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
    objectClass: olcBdbConfig
    olcDatabase: bdb

   # Domain name (e.g. home.local)
   olcSuffix: dc=home,dc=local

   # Location on system where database is stored
   olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap

   # Manager of the database
   olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local
   olcRootPW: admin

   # Indices in database to speed up searches
   olcDbIndex: uid pres,eq
   olcDbIndex: cn,sn,mail pres,eq,approx,sub
   olcDbIndex: objectClass eq

   # Allow users to change their own password
   # Allow anonymous to authenciate against the password
   # Allow admin to change anyone's password
   olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword
   by self write
   by anonymous auth
   by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local" write
   by * none

   # Allow users to change their own record
   # Allow anyone to read directory
   olcAccess: to *
   by self write
   by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local" write
   by * read
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to connect via CLI?

```
ldapsearch -x -D "cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local" -W -h <hostname>
```

Do check your syslog, slapd by default logs its output there.

You can also use slapcat, which must be executed locally, to know whether your database was created or not (slapd would break if otherwise, anyway). It will output the first database avaliable. Use the flag **-n** to extract an specific database:

```
slapcat -n <database number>
```

My bets are that you're authenticating against the wrong database.